# AV Capture Contents of a *View* to a Movie

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I know how to use AVFoundation to capture the contents of a *screen* to a movie file, but I'd like to instead capture the contents of an NSView instead. My app does some things in a view and currently to generate a movie file I have to record the whole screen (cropped of course). It would be much easier on the user if the app could be in the background and still be recording the session. I've considered maybe creating a fake screen and trying to reflect the contents of the view there, but that seems overcomplicated.

Comment: Are you displaying with `-drawRect` or a layer tree within your view?

Comment: The view is a web view actually. I am attempting to capture the contents of an Electron app's contents.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success with a pure CALayer tree using a CARenderer into an old-style OpenGL context into a CVOpenGLTextureCache / AVAssetWriter, then also displaying it to a regular GL view or layer for display.

There are some quirks in the old renderer, however, so you might have to tweak things a bit to make it work with retina, etc. Haven't tried with a proper NSView tree, and the CA maintainers were surprised it worked at WWDC. So future support may be limited.

Seems like a good request though, I'd be happy to reference your radar.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICR, there is no explicit API to capture an NSView. What you'd have to do is render it frame-by-frame, or if the view's interesting content is all layer-based, using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`.

The former approach (render frame-by-frame) is probably going to be slow, and some compositing methods will render incorrectly in the software renderer. It boils down to using an `AVAssetWriter` and `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`, and feeding it frames. It's fairly straightforward (but a lot of code) to create a pixel buffer that shares memory with a `CGBitmapContext`, then create sample buffers from those pixel buffers, then feed those sample buffers into an asset writer pipeline, and then write that asset to disk as an m4v file.

The latter (render some coreanimation) approach is... a lot of work. Would need to know a lot more about the contents being rendered to suggest an exact approach.

Comment: The documentation for `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` says "Avoid using layers that are associated with `UIView` objects." My understanding is that the tool would become the parent of the layer, making it no longer good for showing the NSView's content.